# How to call a login function in TestCafe from a Utility class?

Tags: typescript, testcafe

I am new to TestCafe and TypeScript.
I want to create a login function from a utility class and call it in beforeEach method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following articles to see how to organize your code in utility classes in the most optimal way:

https://testcafe.io/documentation/402826/guides/concepts/page-model
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402845/guides/advanced-guides/authentication